# if statement in where clause because of outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to select some value from the table with where clause in 2 condition.

```
select a.value1
b.value2
c.value3
from a,b,c
where
a.header_id = b.header_id
and b.line_id = c.line_id(+)
```

if c.line_id is not null i have more where clause like

```
c.active = 'Y'
c.active_date > sysdate
```

any ideas, how to make this statement work ?

Comment: This looks like Oracle code.  May we remove the Postgres tag?

Comment: sry, i want to tag plsql.

Comment: Can you rewrite your query using modern syntax?  _Remove_ the commas from the `FROM` clause and use explicit joins.

Comment: `(+)` oooooh... I remember that from the early 90s! Please transform to `outer join` -- it hurts my eyes.

Comment: The purpose of the `(+)` in the original query is to create an outer join (*in an ancient arcane syntax*) any subsequent predicates referring to the table `c` must also have `(+)` tacked on too e.g. `c.active(+) = 'Y'` **Or** (way better) use the more readable modern syntax as shown below.

Answer (score 4):

The best way of making this statement work is to rewrite it using ANSI joins:

```
SELECT
    a.value1
,   b.value2
,   c.value3
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.header_id = b.header_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON b.line_id = c.line_id
```

Now there is no doubt as to the place for the additional condition - since it applies only to rows in which `c` is non-null, you add it to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    a.value1
,   b.value2
,   c.value3
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.header_id = b.header_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN c ON b.line_id = c.line_id
                 AND c.active = 'Y'
                 AND c.active_date > sysdate
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing this query 25 years into the futur.. erm... present.